# Display variable label instead of value

Tags: pytorch, streamlit

I created two lists as dropdown menus in streamlit.

```
list = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
list1 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 11]
select_options = [list,list1]

dropdown = st.selectbox('Select Option', options=select_options)
```

Right now the dropdown menu displays 2,3,5,7,11 & 1,2,5,7,11. Is there a way to display the variable label instead so the dropdown menu would show list & list1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two select boxes, the first selectbox is to make the choice as to which list you want to use and the second selectbox will let you make the choice of the elements in the selected list.

**Note:** It's not appropriate to name a variable after `list` because it is a python built-in function. So I renamed your `list` variable to `list1`

```py
import streamlit as st

list1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
list2 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 11]

get_list = st.selectbox('Select List Option', ("List1", "List2"))
select_options = []
if get_list == "List1":
    select_options = list1
elif get_list == "List2":
    select_options = list2

dropdown = st.selectbox(f'Select Option of {get_list}:', select_options)
```

**Output:**
[image]